# Selenium, getting the value of an element off a webpage

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to use selenium to get a value off of a webpage.

```
<span class="dashValues ng-binding">1,672 W</span>
```

Specifically, I would like the 1,627.
I have tried ```

````
span_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("dashValues ng-binding") and  
ontent.find_elements_by_xpath("//html//body//div//div[3]//div//ui-view//div//ng-include//div//div[1]//div[1]//div//div//div[2]//span")```
````

with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

[image: link to html]

Comment: you want to get that specific value from the `span` tag

Comment: Keep in mind, you can also get the element path from inspect, and use the "Copy JS path" (Chrome & Brave). Then retrieve the element by executing JavaScript from Selenium.

Comment: If that's the only element to use class `dashValues`, that would be a way easier way to fetch the value.

Comment: Can you share that page link?

Comment: @Prophet I am unable to share the link. Sorry I should have mentioned that in my question. The link is to a display of a solar panel dashboard that my building uses. I doubt anyone could do any harm from the guest view, but its against my schools privacy rules. Also I am really sorry about how badly this question was worded, I am new to html and selenium. If I have any future questions ill be sure they are better.

Comment: No problem. I see you already accepted an answer here, so I understand the problem is already resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `css selector` does not work in that way :-

cause `dashValues` and `ng-binding` are two different classes in HTML, in case we wanna combine them, we could do it with `.` as below :-

Instead of this

```
span_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("dashValues ng-binding")
```

use this :

```
span_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.dashValues.ng-binding")
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. (I would upvote but I don't have enough reputation points). A second solution I found was to use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "dashValues ng-binding"]')` and then `get_attribute('innerHTML')`